# Use Asp.Net ViewBag value in AngularJs controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to AngularJs and I have a problem using a value from a .Net MVC View to a AngularJs Controller. Below is the relevant code:

AngularJs controller code:

```
app.controller("RatingApiController", function ($scope, RatingApiService) {

var id = $scope.roomId;
})
```

Mvc View code:

```
<div id="tblSubs" ng-controller="RatingApiController" >
    <span ng-init="roomId = @ViewBag.roomId">something</span>
</div>
```

What is the way to have the **roomId value from the Mvc View** in the **id variable inside the AngularJs controller**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead use an init function:

```
<div id="tblSubs" ng-controller="RatingApiController" >
    <span ng-init="init(@ViewBag.roomId)">something</span>
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
app.controller("RatingApiController", function ($scope, RatingApiService) {

    $scope.init = function(roomId) {
        // do something with roomId
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this,

```
ng-init = "roomId = '@ViewBag.roomId'"
```

Or, sending value using a function

```
ng-init ="init('@ViewBag.roomId')"
```

If you have a init funtion in controller

```
$scope.init = function(roomId) {

// do something with roomId
}
```